# Sql Query to display output horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display a query output in a horizontal manner. I have some example data

```
create table TestTable (id number, name varchar2(10))
    insert into TestTable values (1, 'John')
    insert into TestTable values (2, 'Mckensy')
    insert into TestTable values (3, 'Valneech')
    insert into TestTable values (4, 'Zeebra')
    select * from TestTable
```

This gets the output in a vertical view.

```
ID Name
==========
1  John
2  Mckensy
3  Valneech
4  Zeebra
```

However, I need to display it horizontally.

```
ID   1    2       3        4
Name John Mckensy Valneech Zeebra
```

Comment: You want this to be displayed in sql management studio or in ui of your application?

Comment: You want a PIVOT query? See if this helps: https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #TestTable (id int, name varchar(10))

insert into #TestTable values (1, 'John')
insert into #TestTable values (2, 'Mckensy')
insert into #TestTable values (3, 'Valneech')
insert into #TestTable values (4, 'Zeebra')


select *
from 
(
  select *
  from #TestTable
) src
pivot
(
  max(name)
  for id in ([1], [2], [3],[4])
) piv;
```

output

```
1         2       3             4
John    Mckensy Valneech    Zeebra
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic sql query something like below.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select ' + char(39) + 'Name' + char(39) + ' Id,' + stuff((
        select 
        ',max(case [Id] when ' + cast(id as varchar(10)) + '  then name end) ['  
       +  cast([Id] as varchar(10)) + ']'
        from TestTable
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '');

select @sql += 'from TestTable;';
exec(@sql);
```